# Open Partial View on button click inside a modal asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

```
    function SimpleAjaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/Register",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#modalsignupbody").html(result);
                $('#signup').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
            }
        });
    }
```

BUTTON CALL:

```
<button id="SignUpbtn" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="SimpleAjaxCall();">Sign Up</button>
```

MODAL:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="signin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign in</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its not working i am able to go inside the controller function but i am not getting any result in the below code:

```
 success: function (result) {
```

My Controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return PartialView("_Register");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you're receiving some sort of error, try to check the "Network" tab of FireBug or any other tool you are using right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Account/_Register.cshtml");
    }
```

if its in Views/Shared folder then:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Sahred/_Register.cshtml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#modalsignupbody can not be found anywhere in your view and the id of the modal is #signup in the ajax call, but #signin in the view. The html should be populated into "modal-content".

Try:

```
function SimpleAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/Register",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#modal-body").html(result);
            $('#signin').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: true,
                show:     true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Besides, there is no need to use an ajax call back when bootstrap can do it all for you. In your case though, you would need to return all the header/footer etc, or make use of a template.

For that you would use:

```
$('#SignUpbtn').click(function (e) {
    $("#signin").modal({
            backdrop:   true,
            keyboard:   true,
            remote:     "/Account/Register",
            show:       true
    })

})
```

BUTTON CALL:

```
<button id="SignUpbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sign Up</button>
```